# Get clicked key in knockout custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say we have following situation:

**HTML**

```
<div>   
    <p>Price: <input data-bind='priceValue: price, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'' /></p> 
</div>
```

**KO**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.price = ko.observable();
};

ko.bindingHandlers.priceValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //Here I want to get key which force this action
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And in update function of my priceValue binding I want to get which key force call update.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean on "key"?

Comment: When somebody click 'a' I had to know that somebody clicked 'a'. In my case most important thing is to handle Backspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your binding handler's `init` (or the `update`), you could set a jQuery listener on the target element for key clicks.

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          $(element).on('keyup', function(e){
               if(e.which === YOURKEYCODE){
                    // do something
               }
          });
    },
```

For example, the code for the **Backspace** key is **8**, so you would use `if(e.which === 8)`

Comment: The code in the OP uses "afterkeydown".  The jquery event uses "keyup".  You should probably match the two.(At least for readability sake...)